# Tab Bar view cannot change values on screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller, background-process

I have a function which receives network messages and should display these in a view with its own controller as part of a tabbed application.

When connection is established, messages are being received regardless of whether the view(or tab) is the active one.

Although I receive and can process the messages in the current view, **I cannot change the text values of variables on the screen from that same function**. NSLog outputs perfectly normal processing and the only exception is that I cannot assign the resulting strings to the text values of the label and text box. This all worked OK without the tab controller.
here is the function:

```
- (void)displayMessage:(NSDictionary*)message
{
    [activeProcess setText:[[message objectForKey:@"MSG1:"] uppercaseString]];
    [processDetail setText: [message objectForKey:@"MSG2:"]];

    NSLog(@"Process: %@\n Detail: %@",[message objectForKey:@"MSG1:"],[message objectForKey:@"MSG2:"]);
}
```

Comment: Try `[self.view setNeedsDisplay];` at the bottom of you method.

Answer (score 0):

Kjuly - thank you for the suggestion. In this case trying that did not have any effect.

However, I did find out what the problem was: although the view was active and the NSLog did output correctly to the debug screen anything coming into the method, i needed to put explicit instructions in the header and add ***UITextViewDelegate*** to the definition as well as adding the same to the **viewDidLoad** method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    activeProcess.delegate = self;

}
```

That fixed the problem and allowed me to set the text value of the chosen objects as needed.